# passing arguments between functions

Tags: javascript

I have a main function.

```
function google(arg){
       alert(arg);
}

function yahoo(){
     this function requires my arg object passed above.
}
```

I am passing my object to function `google` in another page, but i cannot call `yahoo` method explicitly. Is there any pattern or way where we can pass objects between two functions.

I have heard about `apply and call` method, but not sure about it.

Comment: If you "cannot call `yahoo` method explicitly" then `apply` or `call` won't do any good.  What exactly are you trying to do?  Why can't you call the other function?

Comment: Are you using dynamic JavaScript code or a function name as a string or something?

Comment: By the looks of the code you can explicitly call the yahoo method.

Comment: If you can't call yahoo() explicitly, what _is_ calling it?

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?

```
var theArg;
function google(arg) {
    theArg = arg;
}

function yahoo() {
   // use theArg;
}
```